# Templates making use of class methods

Tags: c++, templates

I have template method and i would like the template method use a specific method from a class to do the operation. Is it possible ?

```
template<typename T>
int minus(T t1,T t2){
return t1-t2;
}
```

And in my apple object class i have a method called getPrice()
How can i combine both.

Is this correct ?

```
template<typename T>
int minus(T t1,T t2){
return t1.getPrice()-t2.getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, but it loses the generality of the first version of the template. That is, it only works for types that have a member function named `getPrice`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you probably want an ordinary function for your type:

```
template <class T>
int minus(T t1, T t2) {
    return t1 - t2;
}

int minus(const apple& t1, const apple& t2) {
    return t1.getPrice() - t2.getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, I would like to know how can i combine with operator overloading for example operator-

Comment: It depends on what the type is supposed to do. I wouldn't expect a type named "apple" to provide an `operator-`; subtracting two apples doesn't make much sense. But for some algorithms, being able to subtract their prices is sensible, and for those algorithms, the `minus` that you're exploring is a good approach.